# TWS Api tick events

Tags: finance, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

IBKR's TWS API provides a `tickPrice` and a `tickSize` method that get called whenever the bid/ask price and size respectively change.

I'm using a Map to store the Bid, Ask, BidSize & AskSize data. My issue here is that the ticks don't appear to be timestamped, and are run asynchronously so if there's a change in the Bid (& therefore most likely a change in the Bid Size too) my map is updated seperately in 2 steps and there can be a brief moment in time when it contains the Bid from the new tick but with the old Bid Size and vice versa leading to incorrect information (for a few ms but still).

Given that my code contains logic that then acts on a change in the Bid/Ask I'm worried it'll lead to problems - is there any way around this issue? I don't understand why IB can't just send everything in one `tick` method instead of splitting it up and causing issues with synchronizing the data.

Oh, and I can't use `reqTickByTickData` because I'm trading options and they don't have that functionality for options yet.

Would appreciate any pointers